# Gravity Forms Signature - From PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, urlencode, hmac, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to translate some existing PHP code to Python. This job connects to gravity forms and queries for certain data. In order to make the query, a signature must be calculated in order to verify the connection.

The Gravity Forms web api gives good PHP directions [here](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/web-api/#get-forms-form-id-entries).

The PHP method is as follows:

```
function calculate_signature( $string, $private_key ) {
    $hash = hash_hmac( 'sha1', $string, $private_key, true );
    $sig = rawurlencode( base64_encode( $hash ) );
    return $sig;
}
```

Based on my understanding of Python and the information about hash-hmac and rawurlencoded from php2python.com, I wrote the following:

```
import hmac, hashlib, urllib, base64
def calculate_signature(string, private_key):
    hash_var = hmac.new(private_key, string, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    sig = urllib.quote(base64.b64encode(hash_var))
    return sig
```

However, the two signatures are not equivalent, and thus Gravity Forms returns a HTTP 403: Bad Request response.

Am I missing something within my translation?

---

Update (11/04/15)

I have now matched my php and python urls. However, I still receive a 403 error.

Comment: I notice in your Python code, you use `base64.b64encode()` even though you haven't imported the `base64` module. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI, I apologize, I did import base64 and just forgot to include it above. I will edit the post appropriately. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the php and python signatures did not match had nothing to do with their `calculate_signature()` methods.

The issue was caused by differing `expires` variables. Php used `strtotime("+60 mins")` which resulted in a UTC time 60 minutes from now. Whereas Python used `datetime.date.now() + timedelta(minutes=60)`. This is also 60 minutes from now, but in your current timezone.

I always want to calculate the `expire` variable in UTC so I replaced my Python calculation with `datetime.datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=60)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) does not encode slashes, for example, as PHP's [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) does. You can use [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) to achieve the desired effect:

```
import hmac, hashlib, urllib, base64
def calculate_signature(string, private_key):
    hash_var = hmac.new(private_key, string, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    sig = urllib.quote_plus(base64.b64encode(hash_var))
    return sig
```

Comment: I have updated my function to include your changes (urllib.quote_plus) and it still does not return the same signature as the php version...

Comment: @dlstadther Do you have an example input for which the signatures differ?

Comment: I got finally got the signatures to match. They were dependent on an 'expires' variable. Php used strtotime("+60 mins") which resulted in a UTC time 60 minutes from now. Python used (datetime.date.now() + timedelta(minutes=60)) which resulted in a time 60 minutes from now in the current time zone.